# Limiting concurrent calls to a third party in Cloud Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm looking at a pipeline that needs to limit calls-in-flight to a third-party system, and thinking about a couple of different approaches.

For a single pipeline, I'm thinking of using no-op [keyed state](https://beam.apache.org/blog/stateful-processing/) approach, such that parallelism is limited to the number of keys. Basically, include this in the relevant stage:

```
// Add a fake state entry to force serialization per-key.
@StateId("force-serialization")
private final StateSpec<ValueState<String>> myStateSpec = StateSpecs.value();
```

For multiple pipelines, I'm thinking of using a secondary leasing system, where we try to claim a lease in `startBundle` (and return it in `finishBundle`).

As a final wrinkle, there are some instances where successive stages will call this same service, and need to share the same in-flight limits. I want this to play nicely with [fusion](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#fusion-optimization), and not have successive stages contending the same leases if they are fused. For example, take successive stages:

```
DoFn<KV<String, Foo>, KV<String, Bar>> Stage1  // Calls third party API
DoFn<KV<String, Bar>, KV<String, Baz>> Stage2  // Calls third party API
```

I'm thinking that I can include a 'sameBundle' flag in Foo that is erased on serialization. If Stage1 + Stage2 are fused, then this flag will pass from Stage1 to Stage2, and I can assume that they'll share the same in-flight behavior. If they aren't, the flag won't be passed, so the two stages will attempt to claim leases independently. This seems like it should be fine from a threading perspective, because the fusion break means that the output of Stage1 will be checkpointed before being consumed by Stage2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using keys to limit parallelism will work well. You could use GroupByKey instead of KeyedState if you're not actually using the state.

Using a secondary leasing system would work too, though you rightly point out possible issues with fusion. The primary difficulty here would be distinguishing between two DoFns that are fused (and would never execute concurrently and could share a lease) vs. two DoFns that are processing different work items in parallel. If acquiring/releasing leases from the external system is too expensive to do per-element, you could have some kind of a two-level system where the worker holds a per-worker (static) lease manager that can quickly service lease request/release parameters locally backed by leases from the secondary system that are acquired/released at a larger timescale. This could work well for streaming and batch.

Another option could be to set up a proxy service that sits in front of the third-party system and handles the global throughput limiting.

For all of these one would need to consider any adverse effects on autoscaling if workers are spending most of their time idle waiting for leases.